# How do I distinguish two emails from one string in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string (from a page source) that contains two emails:

```
<span class="inlinemeta">From:                               D Hui &lt;dhui@tcmclinic.com&gt;
Sent:                                 Friday, June 18, 2010 12:57 PM
</span>
<span class="inlinemeta">To:                                    'pcox@medcoc.org'
Subject:                               New med approved?
```

What I need is to pull out the four attributes: SentFrom, SentTo, SentOn, Subject.

With the help on stackoverflow, I am able to get SentOn, I now am stuck on how to distinguish the two emails.
Considering the actual raw text to be parsed could differ from one to one with minors like From may include a prefix (in this case it's D Hui) or may not (like the second email), and To could also be like that, so I really need a bit flexible on the solution.

Thank you very much in advance, I just started python a week ago so please pardon me if the question is too simple or too easy to find a solution online.

At the meantime, I surely will try myself to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: `from = re.findall(r'From:(.*?)Sent:',your_string)` and 
`to = re.findall(r'To:(.*?)Subject:',your_string)`

Comment: Thank you, I figured out myself but for unknown reason stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post answer. I'll try to see if I can break down my solution in a few comments

Comment: reg_datetime = "(?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday), "\
 "(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)"\
 " \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)"
senton = re.findall(reg_datetime, result)

Comment: reg_subject = '(?P<Subject>Subject.+)'
subject = re.findall(reg_subject, result)
pos=subject[0].index("Subject:")
subject = subject[0][pos+8:].strip()

Comment: regemail = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
email = re.findall(regemail, result)
From=email[0]
To=email[1]

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general solution that breaks the text into lines. It also uses `split` and `strip` to handle the date and subject without a regex.

```
import re

message_text = """
<span class="inlinemeta">From:                               D Hui &lt;dhui@tcmclinic.com&gt;
Sent:                                 Friday, June 18, 2010 12:57 PM
</span>
<span class="inlinemeta">To:                                    'pcox@medcoc.org'
Subject:                               New med approved?
"""

email_regex = r"[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
for line in message_text.split('\n'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if 'From:' in line:
        e_from = re.search(email_regex, line).group(0)
    if 'Sent:' in line:
        e_sent = line.split(':')[1].strip()
    if 'To:' in line:
        e_to = re.search(email_regex, line).group(0)
    if 'Subject:' in line:
        e_subject = line.split(':')[1].strip()

print "e_from    = %s" % e_from
print "e_sent    = %s" % e_sent
print "e_to      = %s" % e_to
print "e_subject = %s" % e_subject
```

**Output**

```
e_from    = dhui@tcmclinic.com
e_sent    = Friday, June 18, 2010 12
e_to      = pcox@medcoc.org
e_subject = New med approved?
```

The `email_regex` comes from [emailregex.com](http://emailregex.com/)